# JavaScript, changing the value of an object with arrays without affecting the entire object

Tags: javascript, arrays, immutability

I have tried to change the values of the arrays in the "formDataArray" object it keeps however rewriting the entire object once I make any change. This may be a question of immutability, I have tried researching but I have throw in the towel. How do I change the values of the arrays in "formDataArray" in a persistent manner;

```
  if ((value, pos, name)) {
      var formDataArray = {
          code: [],
          desc: [],
          qty: [],
          prices: [],
          line_price: []
      };
      switch (name) {
          case "description":
              formDataArray.desc[pos - 1] = value;
              break;
          case "code":
              formDataArray.code[pos - 1] = value;
              break;
          case "qty":
              formDataArray.qty[pos - 1] = value;
              break;
          case "price":
              formDataArray.prices[pos - 1] = value;
              break;
          case "line_price":
              formDataArray.line_price[pos - 1] = value;

              break;
          default:
      }
      console.log(formDataArray);
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried taking the object declaration out of your `if` statement?

Comment: `formDataArray` is created inside the `if` block. Did you mean to create it somewhere else? Also, `(value, pos, name)` just means `name`.

Comment: is `value` an array?

Comment: Not exactly related, but how is the `if` condition supposed to work here?

Comment: You have given us very little information on your code: is it wrapped inside a function? Do you want to update the object `formDataArray` or create a new one out of `value`, `pos` and `name`? What do you mean by 'persistent manner'?

Comment: As @Ry- mentioned, since you're creating the variable inside of the `if` block, it's likely that that is what you are seeing when you say "rewriting". If you declare the variable elsewhere, and then run this block say, inside of its own function, the data should persist and update.

Comment: @Ivan yes, exactly

Comment: So you have your object `formDataArray` and you want a function to modify its contents right?

Comment: I have tried taking out the if block but to no avail, for clarification I am trying to update the object "formDataArray" with new values from the given variables. By persistent here is what I mean, every time I console.log(formDataArray) I get only the most recent update.

Comment: @VictorHerasmePerez .. yes

Comment: @DavidMbwana then the answer given by Ivan is 99.99% close to what you want

Comment: For context purposes ----I put the if statement to ensure the values of the variables are present before running the function

Comment: You have no function declaration in your code. You need one if you wish to proceed. Check my answer below which explains how to.

Comment: @Ivan , that worked. Thank you.

Comment: @DavidMbwana, No problem happy to have helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if that's what you're looking for: I understand correctly you want to build an `update()` function that allows to update the content contained in the object `formDataArray`.

In this case, define a new function, no need for an if statement. The function will take as arguments the necessary information concerning the modification and make those changes in the existing array (not a new one).

Here is an example code:

```js
var formDataArray = {
  code: [193, 843, 393],
  desc: ['pen', 'table', 'cards'],
  qty: [1, 2, 3],
  prices: [5, 50, 10],
  line_price: [3, 2, 1]
};


let update = function(value, pos, name) {
  switch (name) {
    case "description":
      formDataArray.desc[pos - 1] = value;
      break;
    case "code":
      formDataArray.code[pos - 1] = value;
      break;
    case "qty":
      formDataArray.qty[pos - 1] = value;
      break;
    case "price":
      formDataArray.prices[pos - 1] = value;
      break;
    case "line_price":
      formDataArray.line_price[pos - 1] = value;

      break;
    default:
  }
  return formDataArray;

}

console.log(formDataArray)
update(12, 2, 'price')
console.log(formDataArray)
```

I have added some sample data in `formDataArray`. Watch the console to see the change made in the array of prices.

Answer (score 0):

The formDataArray is initialized every time you edit the Object. Define the object way above the if statement, make it the first first line in your code:

```
var formDataArray = {
      code: [],
      desc: [],
      qty: [],
      prices: [],
      line_price: []
    };


if ((value, pos, name)) {
    switch (name) {
      case "description":
        formDataArray.desc[pos - 1] = value;
        break;
      case "code":
        formDataArray.code[pos - 1] = value;
        break;
      case "qty":
        formDataArray.qty[pos - 1] = value;
        break;
      case "price":
        formDataArray.prices[pos - 1] = value;
        break;
      case "line_price":
        formDataArray.line_price[pos - 1] = value;

        break;
      default:
    }
    console.log(formDataArray);
  }
```